# Saving Rendered images with Semitransparent alpha

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, transparency

Recently Blender started messing up my normals after saving them.
The semi transparent glow is now clipped away and I'm only left with a steaming pile of doggy doo.
This happens regardless if I'm using cycles or eevee (I know cycles needs a node setup for this kind of stuff but it doesn't work, i tried everything i could find and could come up with).
In the screenshot you can see a default blender cube scene with bloom enabled and transparent film.
You can see the glow behind my settings window.

Blender never did this before. I have no Idea what changed. This happens across different computers too and old blender versions are affected too. Life ahs no meaning.
[image: settings and result]

Comment: the glow or other alpha effects are not saved, maybe you're talking about that problem?

Comment: I have done that in the past with no problems though. I had finished projects that hinged on that feature. Was I hallucinating all of that?

Comment: I guess so, there are some tricks to solve the problem but I haven't tested any of them, maybe try that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=tmb5HRU1cUo

Comment: i guess I was hallucinating then. appreciate the link. the person is saving it on a black background though which is not usable for my case. still trying to get it to run with some compositing nodes.